# How to test Administration REST API of Keycloak using postman?

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to test the Administration REST API of Keycloak using Postman, follow below documentation
`https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/7.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource`

I am able to to get the initial token using 
`http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token`

But how to call other API using above token.
For eg - as per keycloak doc- **GET /{realm}/users** should be used for getting all users in realm, But I am not able to get proper response while hitting above url.

Tried - http://localhost:8280/auth/dev/users and other combination.
Can someone specify the complete url for any one API ?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://localhost:8280/auth/admin/realms/dev/users?briefRepresentation=false .
I assume your realm is "dev".

Comment: This is also not working, response is 403, Forbidden.

Comment: You have to add the token you generate in the step before on the Authorization Tab
Select "BEARER" as Type and paste the token zo the Token Field
Press Preview Request and then "Send" again

Comment: I was trying with token, using grant type client credential, but It seems I need to assign realm-admin role to the user. This specific user's token can only be used to invoke Rest Admin API. Thanks for your reply !

Comment: If you want to work with client ID and secret you have to configure the client with "Access Type" confidential. This can be only done on creation.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.
To invoke any Rest Admin API, we need to assign "realm-admin" client role to any specific user. Using that user need to request token and pass it as Authorization header.

I got it as trial attempts and asked my friend who worked with Keycloak, but I love to see if these steps there in Keycloak docs or can be documented in Keycloak docs.

I was not assigning the user role earlier, and requesting token just as "Client Credential" grant type, which was not working.